# Looking for lazy loading server/client ActiveRecord ORM for Node.js

Tags: node.js, activerecord, orm, lazy-loading

I'm new to node.js and I'm looking for an Active-Record-style ORM (to whichever database - any would be great).  But in particular, I'm hoping to find one with these qualities:

- Same interface on both client and server.
- If information is already on the client, then that information is used unless it is deemed "stale".
- If information is *not* already on the client, then it's retrieved from the server - though there should be bundling of requests so that you're not issuing a ton of http requests.
- Simple (enough).

Is it out there?

Comment: Why do you need a database that has interface for the client..?

Comment: Why not? It seems useful to address your data the same way from the server or from the client.  I'm thinking about combining this concept with a client/server templating framework so that I can build my web page on either side.

Comment: You can do that with CouchDB :)

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with CouchDB - do you have a link to some good reading material?  That I could find immediately, CouchDB only provides a web interface, but nothing having to do with lazy loading, staleness handling, and bundling of requests.

Comment: Well the thing is CouchDB (which is a NoSQL database) is RESTful, so it can be accessed from both server side and client side. Look up more info about it and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

there is a great framework for Node called meteor:

[meteor](http://www.meteor.com/)

it seems to do what you wish and even more.